# Vue - how to add &#10; to component's prop

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to add a line break to a component's props using the 
 but when I do so I get an error.

does anyone have a solution?

code:

```html
<template>
  <section class="w-screen h-screen bg-slate-700 grid place-items-center">
    <div class="mb-12">
      <div class="text-8xl">Title</div>
      <div class="m-8 text-center text-3xl">
        <Writer
          :array="[
            'Code 1',
            'line 1&#10; line 2',
          ]"
          :typeSpeed="100"
          :iterations="1"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Is that an html entity? How are you using the prop, in the template?

Comment: Can you explain abit more? Also, include the error and the code you have tried.

Comment: Can't you use `\n` here?

Comment: doesn't work ;-; @kissu

Comment: It depends how you decode it on the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\n` character in the string and then the css `white-space` property in the consuming element.

Here a working example.

On the Writer parent use the `\n` character for the new line like:

```html
<Writer
  :array="[
    'Code 1',
    'line 1\n line 2',
   ]"
   :typeSpeed="100"
   :iterations="1"
/>
```

Inside the Writer component you should add the `white-space` property to your css element like:

```html
<template>
  <div 
    class="break-lines" 
    v-for="arrayElement in array">
      {{ array Element }} 
    </div>
</template>
<style>
  .break-lines {
    white-space: break-lines;
  }
</style>
```

This should do the trick ;)